# raspberry pi vlc-python no sound

Tags: python, raspbian, vlc

I have a python script that plays a video on system boot. The video has audio but when the system starts and the video plays, no audio can be heard. I have set the mute function to False and volume to 100% but nothing plays. However, if I play the video from desktop via the standard vlc application, there is audio. Then, if i run the script again and the video plays automatically from the python script, there is audio. Whats the problem here?

UPDATE: I realized i didnt have alsa-base and pulseaudio installed on my pi. After installing them, both methods did not give audio.

Comment: share logs and code please

Answer (score 0):

Create or edit the file /etc/asound.conf
For headphone output:

pcm.!default {
type hw
card 0
}

ctl.!default {
type hw
card 0
}

For HDMI output:

pcm.!default {
type hw
card 1
}

ctl.!default {
type hw
card 1
}